# SSRS Table wrap has a duplicate row on the end

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

Using SQL Server 2017; I created a report with a few columns. Added the logic to wrap(repeat) the columns to the right on the page.

It works fine. Except the first record in the second set of columns is duplicated as the last record of the second set of columns. It appears to be the only one.  The record in the stored procedure once.

On the report example 'f' is the duplicate.

```
            Page 1
Col1 Col2 Col3  Col1 Col2 Col3
==============  ==============
a    b    c     d    e    f
.
.
v    w    x     y    z    f (again)
```

Comment: Would help if you share 'the logic'

Comment: I went with using the Ceiling expression on the table groups.  Row Group
=ceiling(rownumber(nothing) / 2)

Column Group
=ceiling(rownumber(nothing) mod 2)